# Asynchronous data processing

Tags: opencl

I am new in OpenCl. I was wondering if you could answer my following question.

I have a queue of data packets which acts like router queues. The packets arrive, store in the queue, then processed by the router. Finally, they are inserted to the out-going queue. 
I am trying to use OpenCl to process the packets concurrently. I know that we can use the buffers, for example, to transfer data between the host and OpenCl devices. We load the buffers with input/output data. Then, we set the kernel parameters using these input/output buffers. when the kernels running are done, we read the data from the OpenCl devices.

My question is that, how can I write/read a buffer for each single data packet independently of the other packets?
In other words, suppose one data packet arrives, the router needs to process it on a computing device (e.g. core #1 on GPU). Then another packets arrives. The router needs to process the second packet on a different computing device (e.g. core #2 on GPU). The processing of these two packets  are actually happening concurrently but asynchronously. How this could be implemented in OpenCl?

Thanks for your reply in advance.
Regards,
Alireza.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a ring buffer of OpenCL buffers to hold your incoming data, and as you fill them enqueue kernels to work on them. You're only going to get good performance if the kernels have parallel data to work on. Even GPUs that can work on multiple kernels at the same time that number is small (like perhaps 2). The real power is the parallel computation within a kernel, otherwise your hardware will be idle.

To get kernels to run in parallel you need to use separate command queues since using a single command queue implies serial execution (unless it is an out-of-order command queue, but those are not widely supported).

Comment: Thanks Dithermaster.